# Laravel Error stored in session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm learning laravel (currently using 5.0.34 version) and I have a post request that when encounters an error enters this piece of code

```
$message = new MessageBag(["register" => Lang::get("errors.cant_checkout")]);
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($message);
```

And the result is correct, he redirects to the same view and I can access the $error variable.
The problem is **sometimes** the error keeps stored on session, so it will output the $error everytime I enter the page.
How can this happen? Am I doing something wrong?

Expected : after output first time, the $error gets off the Session

Comment: if I were you, I would upgrade to latest 5.0.x version first before further investigating this issue

Comment: sorry, version is 5.0.34. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I found out that what's causing the problem is an installed plugin called DebugBar. After disabling it everything is running smooth!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are simply flashing the error message into the view using `withErrors->`. The flashed data will only be available during the subsequent HTTP request, so it will not be saved.

But, I think the problem you are having is that by default `$errors` is sent to every view, so it will always be set.  In your view, you will need to check if there are any actual error messages to display (as shown below). Or you can flash a different piece of data, like `->with('specific_error', $message)` and look for `$specific_error` in your view.

```
 @if($errors->any())
   // do work
   <ul>
     @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
       <li>{{ $error }}</li>
     @endforeach
   </ul>
 @endif
```

Comment: in subsequent requests if i print the Session I get this error stored in there. So I dont't have any clue of what's going on